# How can I put 2 buttons with images Vertically in a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Im using tkinter and trying to create a toolbar located on the left side going vertically, I already have a toolbar on the top of the frame filled in going horizontaly however can't figure out how to make a second one on the left, with all the buttons.

This is the code that I have:

```
    infobar = Frame(master, bg="#ecf0f1", bd=1, relief=GROOVE)
    infobar.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=None)
    infobarr = Label(toolbar, bg="#ecf0f1", text='           ')
    infobarr.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)     
    poundToKgButton = Button(infobar, highlightbackground="#ecf0f1", image=eimg20, relief=FLAT, command=self.scale)
    poundToKgButton.image = eimg20
    createToolTip(poundToKgButton, "Conversion - Pound To KG")
    poundToKgButton.pack(side=LEFT)       
    calculatorButton = Button(infobar, highlightbackground="#ecf0f1", image=eimg19, bd=1, relief=FLAT, command=self.calc)
    calculatorButton.image = eimg19
    createToolTip(calculatorButton, "Calculator")
    calculatorButton.pack(side=LEFT, anchor="sw")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `side=TOP` if you want things stacked vertically. The containing widget has empty space. When you use `pack`, you're telling tkinter which side of that empty space to put the widget.

Here is a good example of exactly what happens when you call pack: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26